# Stuck on a Database design issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design

Say I have the following tables:

- GearType : snowboard/helmet/shoes/whatever
- GearModel : which describes the manufacturer, size, and GearType
- Gear : represents a physical instance of a gear, belongs to a GearModel and describes its barcode, number of times it has been worn...
- Member : a person who may be assigned a Gear for each existing geartype
- GearAssignation : has a double PK MemberId/GearTypeId so a Member can be assigned 0..1 gear per geartype, also has FK GearId

My question is :
Since a Gear cannot be assigned to more than 1 Member at once,
how to make up a relation between Gear and GearAssignation of cardinality 1 to 0..1 ?

At best I managed to do this using a relation between Gear.Id and GearAssignation.GearId, with an unique key (remember it cannot be the PK because of the double PK MemberId/GearTypeId) on GearId.
But I'd love to get rid of that UK because my software development tool doesn't recognize it.

As suggested, here is the diagram from SSMS :
[image: all irrelevant columns have been deleted]

Bringing heavy changes to the current model is not a problem at all for me atm.
Suggestions ?

PS : dunno if it helps, I'm using Microsoft's SQL Server 2008

Comment: Can you print screen your SQL Diagram from within SSMS and upload it - might help to provide a visual aid

Comment: I suggest you edit your title to ask a specific question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd do this by having a field in Gear for the member_id who it is currently assigned to.

Comment: +1: drop the GearAssignment table completely.  The purpose of a table like that is only to allow a many to many relationship.

Comment: @user348019 - I would think that GearTypeId would be an attribute of Gear, not assignation.  The way your model is setup right now a member is associated to a GearType, not a Gear, which is what I'm reading you need to do.  Jaydee has made an astute observation.

Comment: I'm going to follow this. The constraint of 1 Gear/GearType/Member will then be enforced by the app itself since I've been told that the conceptual data model wasn't the right place for it.Thank you for your help